# Windows authentication unable to authenticate system user or ADFS user

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-7, windows-authentication

I have an aspnetcore2.1 api and is configured with windows authentication using the below code. This should work for all the users that are in my ADFS server which is in the same network and the machine that I am trying to access the site from is included in the same domain of the ADFS server.

In the app, in the ConfigureServices section

```
        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

and in the Configure section

```
        app.UseAuthentication();
```

I have also added a web.config file for the application when I deployed which looks like below

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
  </handlers>
  <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet"
              arguments=".\sampleapi.dll"
              stdoutLogEnabled="true"
              stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
              forwardWindowsAuthToken="true"/>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows"/>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
    <allow roles="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

And now the site is asking for credentials as expected when I try to access the app.

I tried different user accounts from the machine and the ADFS server accounts, none of them were working. Is there something that I have missed? I have made sure NTLM is the first one in the list on the provider list in the IIS configuration.
I changed the app pool identity to a custom user which is from the ADFS users who have admin access to the current machine (also this is where the site lives).

Comment: You made a few mistakes. All settings in `<system.web>` are irrelevant as ASP.NET Core won't read them at all. You need to enable Windows authentication on IIS (and disable anonymous authentication there). About why the browser prompts for credentials, read IIS log files to see which kind of 401 you hit (substatus code matters).

Comment: I did also enable the windows auth in IIS and disable Anonymous. That's when it started to prompt me for credentials. The error message on the screen has 0xc000006d code after multiple login attempts. I will configure the IIS logs and see what is going on.

Comment: I figured it out, The problem is that I am accessing the application in the same machine where the application is served from the IIS. It is just going into a loop of asking credentials. I just tried exposing that site to another machine and the site started to work as soon as I entered the credentials for the ADFS user.

Comment: Then you hit the famous loopback check https://west-wind.com/wconnect/weblog/ShowEntry.blog?id=939